# eval to import a module

Tags: python, eval

I can't import a module using the `eval()` function.

So, I have a function where if I do `import vfs_tests as v` it works. However, the same import using `eval()` like `eval('import vfs_tests as v')` throws a syntax error.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `exec`:

```
exec 'import vfs_tests as v'
```

`eval` works only on expressions, `import` is a statement.

`exec` is a function in Python 3 :  `exec('import vfs_tests as v')`

To import a module using a string you should use  `importlib` module:

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module('vfs_tests')
```

In Python 2.6 and earlier use `__import__`.

Comment: A word of warning: exec is very powerful.  If part of the string you are exec'ing comes from an untrusted source, then exec is also extremely dangerous.

Comment: With __import__ for py <= 2.6, note that it doesn't leave the imported name defined, like a regular import would.

Answer (score 18):

Actually. if you absolutely need to import using `eval` (for example, code injection), you can do it as follow in Python 3, since `exec` is a function:

```py
eval("exec('import whatever_you_want')")
```

For example:

```
>>> eval('exec("from math import *")')
>>> sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
```

Answer (score 9):

My little trick if you want to pass all the code as string to eval function:

```py
>>> eval('exec("import uuid") or str(uuid.uuid4())')
'bc4b921a-98da-447d-be91-8fc1cebc2f90'
>>> eval('exec("import math") or math.sqrt(2)')
1.4142135623730951
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `__import__` inside of `eval` to import something.

```
eval("__import__('os').system('ls')")
```