# Extended import with a function in Python

Tags: python, function, import, nameerror

It's my CS homework - Exercise 12-6 in Wesley Chun's "Core Python Programming." The objective is to imitate extended import with a function like when `import ... as` was not implemented. These are my attempts, both of which yield errors:

```
def importAs(name):
    eval('import '+name)
    ret = eval(name)
    eval('del '+name)
    return ret

foo = importAs('os')
```

This yields a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `import os` in `File "<string>", line 1`, while:

```
def importAs(name):
    import name
    ret = name
    del name
    return ret

foo = importAs(os)
```

yields a `NameError: name 'os' is not defined` at `foo = importAs(os)`.

Can anybody explains the reason and a solution please?

EDIT: please keep it 2.x only :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [eval to import a module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136772/eval-to-import-a-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` can evaluate only expression. And `import` is a statement, so it won't work.

You should use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) module for your task.

Also take a look at [eval to import a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136772/eval-to-import-a-module)

Comment: Which of my code blocks are you referring to?

If it's the second one, then after changing it to `foo = importAs('os')`, I get the error below:

`ImportError: No module named name` at `import name` in `importAs`.

Comment: Well that works, but as it is not mentioned in the book, it might not be the best solution for this. Could you tell me what is wrong with my second attempt?

Comment: yes. `os` is not defined before you try use it. you can read https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt to see correct syntax.

Comment: Well I can see that it is not in the namespace, thus the error.
I'm gonna settle with exec for now, but hopefully I will find a way to pass a module as a parameter later.