# Drawbacks of calling Python's reload multiple times a second

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, reload

I want to do some BTLE scanning in the neigbourhood, for this I have the following code

**btlescan.py**

```
import btlescan_handler

proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'stdbuf', '-oL', 'hcitool', 'lescan'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
  now    = arrow.now()
  output = line.rstrip()
  try:
    reload(btlescan_handler)
    btlescan_handler.process(now, output, storage)
  except:
    pass
```

and **btlescan_handler.py**

```
def process(now, line, storage):
  try:
    mac = line[:17]
    output = str(int(now.float_timestamp * 1000)) + ' -- ' + now.datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d -- %H:%M:%S.%f') + ' -- ' + line
    print output, mac
  except:
    pass
```

Since BTLE devices are very chatty by nature, this will cause the `reload` function to get called multiple times a second.

The `reload` is there so that I can modify the `process` function in `btlescan_handler` in realtime, instead of constantly restarting the script for every minor change.

I am aware of, and do use `inotify`, I have a script which usually does handle all the watching/unwatching/reloading of python scripts when they are modified, but for quick and dirty testing of the functionality of `process` I just want to call `reload`.

The core of the question is, what are the drawbacks from doing this, aside from increasing the CPU usage? Could this cause the script, which is running from an SDHC card (Raspberry Pi), to increase the strain of the card, or is this just read from a cache in memory after the text editor has saved the file modifications?

Comment: `reload(btscan_handler)` should be `reload(btlescan_handler)` ?

Comment: You could check the file's modification time, and only reload it if it has changed.

Comment: If you're reading the file frequently it should practically always come from cache.

Comment: @Barmar yes, maybe I should do that, the file modification time thing. I usually opt for `inotify` because there I also save the "check file modification date every x ms" cycles, but it is well suited for this case. But this was just a script hacked together in a couple of minutes, which made the question arise. So it's from cache and only wastes cpu + memory bandwidth?

Comment: If you are rewriting btle_handler.py, then you could just as easily save the new definition of process into a string and eval() it, couldn’t you?

Comment: @barny How would he update that string in the script?

Comment: @barny Not really, that breaks the editor's highlighting/folding/etc features (Bamar has a point there with the updating of the string). Also, It's a tradition not to `eval`. Anyway, does `eval` handle `import` statements?

Comment: But OP is “eval”ing the code he’s written to the file. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet: reload *is* doing eval.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136772/eval-to-import-a-module my code was just a mvp, the handler does a lot more than just print out the mac address.