# Pass a module into variable in python

Tags: python

I wanna something like that :

```
import Variant
x = Variant.Pop1
from x import mid
```

is this possible?

Comment: Can't you simply do `from Variant.Pop1 import mid`?

Comment: @chuck2002 Because I have a list of the file as Variant.Pop1, Variant.Pop2,... and each file has the same function name "mid" like def mid(a,b) but different context. I wanna get result unit test like mid(1,2) mid(1,3) mid(1,4)... from Variant.Pop1, Variant.Pop2,... . I wanna pass Variant.Pop1, Variant.Pop2,.. as a variable of a function

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to import them manually - `from Variant.Pop1 import mid as pop1_mid`, `from Variant.Pop2 import mid as pop2_mid` and so on.

Comment: This is a good question. Can't imagine why its downvoted.

Comment: @tdelaney It may be an interesting question, but there's a very real possibility that it's not the best solution for OP.

Comment: @AMC - that may be true of any program any of us has ever written! OP is giving us a toy example - the real work is in functions that take modules + names. `importlib` will do the trick.

Comment: let's use exec(), like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136772/eval-to-import-a-module)

Answer (score 1):

To import a module from a name in a variable, use `importlib` ([see python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html))

For example:

```
import importlib
import os.path as p
x = p.__name__
q = importlib.import_module(x)
```

Of course, this example is silly because q ends up as with the same value as p, but it demonstrates the syntax. Please provide more detail if this is not what you want.

Another option is to use exec, as in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136772/eval-to-import-a-module)

Comment: That's awesome! I tried exec and it's work exactly what I want. Thanks a lot !!! @Gordon Hopper

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help you, but you could consider the `importlib` module: it allows to make dynamic import like:

```py
from importlib import import_module

module_names = ["Pop1", "Pop2", ...]

def foo():
    for name in module_names:
        module = import_module(name, "Variant")
        module.mid(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is, but this is not a good example of how to import modules, it's a bad practice.

This is exactly what you want to do, but better.

```
from Variant.Pop1 import mid as x

def my_func(var):
   # do something

my_func(x)
```

Example:

```
from random import choice as x

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def my_func(var):
    return var(my_list)

print(my_func(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importlib`. The import specification is like a directory structure using "." to step through module names. A module keeps its "directory name" in `__package__`. So,

```
import importlib
import Variant
x = Variant.Pop1
mid = importlib.import_module(".".join(x.__package, "mid"))
```