# python 3 syntax error while evaluating import line

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

Working on getting seriously into python3.

While trying to eval(generated_code) to parse arguments I get an unexpected syntax error during the eval. Iv'e whittled down the code to a simpler failure case for posting here. The real code nicely defines ap though this fragment does not.

The problem with the fragment is not the undefined ap, but the immediate syntax error in the first line passed to eval. If the code within the triple quotes is passed directly to python3, without the eval, then rather than a syntax error the expected undefined ap problem happens, which for this fragment, is a success.

**Code Fragment**

```
evtxt = '''
import argparse
def sh_add_args(ap):
    # eval ./argparse.py --name0="$0" -- "$@" <<ARGPARSE || exit $?
    ap.add_argument('--arg', type=str, default='ARG', action='store')
    ap.add_argument('--bool', default=False, action='store_true')
    ap.add_argument('--int',  type=int, default=42, action='store')
    return

sh_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Parse arguments for test' )
sh_add_args(sh_parser)
sh_args = ap.parse_args(py_parser.argv)
'''

print("###BEGIN\n" + evtxt + "\n####END")
eval(evtxt)
```

**Unexplained Error**
The actual error follows from python3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp2.py", line 15, in <module>
    eval(evtxt)
  File "<string>", line 2
    import argparse
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**What I want**

I've tried both """ and ''' quotes in the fragment and get the same result.

The triple quotes are just for this demo fragment. The actual `evtxt` is generated reading input line by line using `fileinput.input()`, though the results are the same.

*The goal is to find the stupid thing I'm overlooking to work past the syntax error.*

FYI: any trailing white space has been removed during line reading.

Comment: `eval` is for an _expression_, an `import` is a _statement_. Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17136772/3001761

Comment: `eval` evaluates an expression. What you have is not an expression. You meant to use `exec`.